# How to view a file on PuTTY?

Tags: ssh, putty

I opened a file in PuTTY and I need the file .flag, how do I open it?

I have tried

```
vi index.flag
```

and

```
cp index.flag
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried that?

Comment: Can you run more index.flag?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To list all files in a directory with their permissions run

```
ls -la
```

Make sure your user have at least read permission on the file you need to open

open the file using vi editor (assuming the file you want to open is called .flag)

```
vi .flag
```

you can also use the cat command to just to view the contents of a file

```
cat .flag
```